# How to implement a concurrent hash table with tbb which maps key to values of different types?

Tags: c++, hashmap

My requirement is to implement a concurrent hash table with 2 fields, first one would be the key of type int, while the second one stores data of type integer, char and structure. The obvious way is to define the hash map using

```
typedef concurrent_hash_map<int, void> myTable;
```

But it gives the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:102:11: error: instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second’ as type ‘void’
    _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:102:11: error: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second’ has incomplete type
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:102:11: error: invalid use of ‘void’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:112:26: error: forming reference to void
   _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR pair(const _T1& __a, const _T2& __b)
```

Is there a solution or an alternative?

Comment: The closest thing you may get is `typedef concurrent_hash_map<int, void*> myTable;`. O rbetter consider a valuetype like `boost::any` or `boost::variant`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It shows the following error:    " invalid declarator before ‘myTable’ if i use     typedef concurrent_hash_map<int, void*> myTable;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `void` like that.

What you probably mean is `typedef concurrent_hash_map<int, void*> myTable;`

You would probably be better off using `boost::variant` if boost is viable in your project.

```
//assuming myStruct is your "structure"
typedef boost::variant<int,char,myStruct> myValue;
typedef concurrent_hash_map<int, myValue> myTable;
```